# Why are my Python libraries appearing when I installed Pydev for Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, eclipse-neon

I am new to Python, but am proficient with Java, which I use on Eclipse (Neon), so I downloaded Pydev for Eclipse, but when I attempted to install Pydev, no interpreters showed up. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it (3 times), but the libraries still did not show up. How can I fix this?

This is what showed up when I went to Windows → Preferences on Eclipse

[image]

EDIT: This is what happens when I try to Auto-Configure

[image]

Comment: You have to use the auto config or choose the `python` binary manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that means PyDev wasn't able to find your python.exe automatically and you have to choose "New..." and select it manually in the interpreter preferences page.